# Do I have to use id attr?

Tags: html, css, angular

In angular 2, when I want to style a specific component I use the following:

```
<div #mask id="mask" class="col-xs-12 some-generi-ccss-class"></div>

// in .css
#mask{
  height: 50px;
}
```

In my opinion it seems like a bit of a double handle defining both an id (`id="mask"`) to style with and a ng2 selector string (`#mask`) to use with `@ViewChild('mask')` in my `component.ts` for the one element.

Am I able to drop one of these attributes but still achieve both functionalities? Or is this boilerplate?

Comment: `#mask` is unrelated to styling and unrelated to id. It just allows you to reference the `<div>` from other places in the template or using `@ViewChild()`. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681 to learn what a template variable can be used for.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you want to post this as an answer so I can finish this question with an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#mask` is unrelated to styling and unrelated to "id".
It just allows you to reference the `<div>` from other places within the template from using `@ViewChild(...)`, `@ContentChild(...)` (`@ViewChildren(...)`, `@ContentChildren(...)`).

See for example stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/… to learn what a template variable can be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no and yes :

Coz it looks same but both are different :

`#mask` in div elements shows the `template variable` , so you can access it inside `template` and in `component` , that's part of angular 2

`id="mask"` is `html's` default attribute,

Though if you want to access the div without using #mask , there is way , via 
`document.getElementById('mask')` and remove #mask if you don't want to access it from template side.

Comment: This is just another way , if he wants to.

Comment: He wants to **style** the element, not retrieve it programmatically. So why is the answer "no and yes"? If the question is *Am I able to drop one of these attributes but still achieve both functionalities?*, then the answer is **no**.

Comment: Am I able to drop one of these attributes but still achieve both functionalities? 

yes or no for this.

Comment: not retrieve it programmatically ?  then why he described @ViewChild('mask') , please read whole query. 

And I have just give him option , if he want to access.

Comment: Read the question carefully, especially the part which says **to style with**.